# How can I implement column indexing when defining a function in R?

Tags: r, function, indexing

For a project I am trying to define a function for Anova on all the column of my datadrame. But I always get the error of "Error in [.data.frame`(data, , x) : undefined columns selected" and could not figure it out. Also I am not really sure if the print function will work or not.

```
type_anova = function(feature){
  b=aov(feature~type, wine=df)
  F=summary(b)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]]
  p=summary(b)[[1]][["F value"]]
  if (p <= 0.05){
    message="Reject"
  } else{
    message="Accept"
  }
  print(paste("F Statistics: ", F,"p-value: ", p,"Null Hypothesis: ",message))
}
type_anova(pH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function :

```
type_anova <- function(df, feature, type) {
   b=aov(reformulate(type, feature), df)
   F=summary(b)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
   p=summary(b)[[1]][["F value"]][1]
   if (p <= 0.05)   message="Reject"
   else  message="Accept"
   cat("\nF Statistics: ", F," p-value: ", p," Null Hypothesis: ",message)
}
```

Using it on `mtcars` dataset

```
type_anova(mtcars, "am", "cyl")
#F Statistics:  0.0022  p-value:  11  Null Hypothesis:  Accept
```